# How to add hyperlink to onlyoffice doc with plugin?

Tags: onlyoffice

I am trying to write a plugin in onlyoffice(4.4.3) and the plugin is expected to add a hyperlink to content of current doc.
I spent quit a lot of time to search the related api in onlyoffice doc(https://api.onlyoffice.com/docbuilder/textdocumentapi), but just can't find it. Meanwhile seems the onlyoffice editor can do that in the UI.

My questions are:

1. If it is feasible to add a hyperlink to content of current doc via the public apis?
2. If yes, how to make that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way way to add a hyperlink, but there is an alternative solution - try using PasteHtml method

```
window.Asc.plugin.executeMethod("PasteHtml", ["<a href=\"onlyoffice.com\">link text</a>"]);
```

New methods will be added soon to [the documentation](https://api.onlyoffice.com/plugin/executemethod), we are already working on it